# Set Session in codebehind for an Onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i add Session value in codebehind. I have tried doing it this way but the session does nt have any value.

```
 x is string.
 td1.InnerHtml = "<a href=\"Search.aspx\" onClick=\"Session['catvalue']=" + x + "\">" + x +</a>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is wrong on so many levels...

Comment: Oops. i understand now, why you say that !! Is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using ASP.NET, you would be better off with an ASP:Link and calling an ASP.NET code behind function.

**In your `.aspx` page**

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLink" OnClick="myMethod" Text="Click me!" runat="server" />
```

**In your `.aspx.cs` page (codebehind)**

```
protected void myMethod(object sender, EventArgs e){
  Session['catvalue'] = x; //x is defined somewhere
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the best way. Thanks rlb :)